# Does a secondary world setting need a religion?

Tags: culture, religion

So I have been debating about what to do for the secondary world setting I am developing. My big question is about what to do for the in-universe religion(s). The thing is that I am mostly doing something in a semi-modern world as sort of a transition from steampunk to cyberpunk, so a more fantasy era setting in which this would be more of a focus feels less necessary. My magic system is in the loosely Sanderson style of essentially being a science rather than being spiritual, and so it has no direct religious elements.

In this context, does the world feel unrealistic if I don't have a religion? The downside to a religion in this context is that it is something that would just be bolted on to everything else, as it doesn't really directly connect with the magic system or anything else.

Comment: An entire world having no religion or just one religion needs to be explained, and probably needs subverting at some point -- it turns out there were numerous religions complete with fanatics and bigots, it was just that the narrator or main characters were unaware of them. Consider 21st century Earth: some large areas, such as parts of Europe and China are essentially religion-free. Some very rich and powerful countries, such as the USA, are in a state of acute struggle between the religion-free and the God-fearing parts of their populations. Some large areas are religion-dominated.

Comment: P.S. This is fundamentally an artistic choice. If you want to tell a story set in a religion-free world, fine. If not, not. Setting the story in a religion-free world would contradict the expectations of many readers, so that the story must either revel in this contradiction, or maybe give subtle hints about how that world is different from ours and came to be that way.

Comment: @AlexP "Consider 21st century Earth: some large areas, such as parts of Europe and China are essentially religion-free." I'm curious which large areas of Europe are religion free? I don't doubt you I'm just curious as the where they are as I'm not aware of them.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie: England, France, the Low Countries, Germany excluding Bavaria, the nordic countries. Not *completely* religion-free as there are quite a few Muslims living in those places, but to a large extent. Conversely, what parts of western Europe do you know where religion is still a significant social and political force? Ireland maybe, Spain possibly, what else?

Comment: @AlexP I think you underestimate religion in both China and Europe. There's plenty of big religious political parties in all countries. Most have a solid voter base, allowing them to have a solid presence in many governments. They might not be a priest or iman, but their religious sentiments help shape culture and countries through politics.

Comment: @Trioxidane: Religion is indeed a form of ideology, but most forms of ideology are not religions. (Or else the word religion loses all meaning.)

Comment: Adam, whether or not religion makes sense in your world is an off-topic storybuilding problem, not a worldbuilding problem. If you don't want religion, don't have it. A great many SF stories don't have or rely on religion and the vast majority of consumers don't even notice the lack. Religion makes sense when it's useful to your story. If you're asking from the perspective of *realism,* note that before people *understand* the science of anything they *believe* the "magic forces" that allow things to happen. A world that doesn't have any religion is simply unrealistic.

Answer (score 2):

## Religion to make your world more alive

You say a Religion feels bolted on, but it doesn't need to be. You're thinking fully functional for either the world or the plot. Neither have to be the case. It can just be an addition to enrich both your world or your plot.

Religion is often used in many stories. It is an easily understandable device that can be used or linked to important themes. This can help shape accentuate or any other thing you want in the story.

Yet it can  also be used in a more mundane way. Just having someone having a religion makes a world more relatable and alive. It is like adding the tides to your story. It doesn't need a specific function, but it does make the world that much more feel alive.

If you can't see how to have religion in your story consider the following. It doesn't matter if you are a flat Earth or a round Earth supporter. If either is fired into space most will deny evidence that they are wrong. That is about something tangible. Religion is rooted much more deeply. Even in a highly scientific society it is very possible to have a religion. There is practically no way to disprove religion in any obvious way, so it can endure.

If I misread and you don't want religion in your story at all I say go for it. The more modern a society is the less people are religious. In addition, many philosophy has changed our understanding. This in turn can also reduce our religious views, even to having them removed. This isn't something tied to the (semi-)modern time. There is no reason holding you back from proclaiming that religion hardly/doesn't exist anymore.

### TL:DR

You can have or not have a religion. With a religion you can have it flesh out the world and not have it feel "bolted on". Without it possible in a semi-modern world.

Comment: Religion is a conservative force to help hold society together. In religion, we have ceremonies to reinforce the social order, make everyone feel as though they are included (even if they are separated out), help identify who is in society and who is not, and reinforce the rules of society. The details can be important to a story or simply added as "color".